# Why GoogleNet uses different size of kernels?

Tags: transfer-learning, pre-trained-model

Why GoogleNet uses different size of kernels? And how different size of kernels can be applied to one single image?

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, just in case it's helpful.

For understanding why different filters in GoogLeNet, consider the 3 images below, where the area occupied by the main subject i.e. the cat, is vastly different in each of the images.

[image: Imgur]

So the problem in this kind of image-analysis situation is, salient parts in an image can have extremely large variations in size.

And because of this huge variation in the location of the information, choosing the right kernel size for the convolution operation becomes tough. A larger kernel is preferred for information that is distributed more globally, and a smaller kernel is preferred for information that is distributed more locally.

Hence, as a solution - GoogLeNet authors, thought, why not have filters with multiple sizes operate on the same level? In that case, the network essentially would get a bit “wider” rather than “deeper”.

And so the inception module reflects this. In its naive version, it performs convolution on an input, with 3 different sizes of filters (1x1, 3x3, 5x5). Additionally, max pooling is also performed. The outputs are concatenated and sent to the next inception module.

And for the "How" part of your question, I may want to check **[this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CZNYrkdDrmQ)** of mine - where I am building GoogLeNet from scratch.